# Ubuntu 22.04 does not detect my network printer

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I'm installing Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop from scratch and it does not detect my ethernet connected HP "Color-LaserJet-CM1312nfi-MFP".
I have an old laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 where it has worked fine for years and it still works. I think I originally installed Ubuntu 18.04 or even 12.04 on it and have since upgraded it to 22.04.
I've tried installing HPLIP but it's GUI does not find anything either.
I also tried switching to another router as I can't ping the printer from any of the two laptops but maybe that's normal?
What's a good next step to get it to work?

Comment: review page 48 Chapter 5 Connectivity of https://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01424292.pdf in order to follow instructions on installing the printer on a network. You should be able to see the IP address by logging in to your router (usually 192.168.1.1 by default) where the printer should be listed in the admin function.

Comment: Thanks for your response @graham! I did see my printer in the router. But my VPN was blocking the traffic on my new laptop...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had two problems here.

1. The network printer could not be found and I could not ping my printer from the new laptop. The issue was that my VPN service was blocking the traffic. The solution was to enable Local network sharing in Mullvad VPN settings.
2. My printer model was not in the list of printers. I installed the hplip package to remedy this. I'm not sure if I had to do this as I was trying to manually add the printer before I had solved problem #1.

Comment: great that you found a solution in the end.